# Problems with URL generator in Frozen-flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to freeze a flask site with frozen-flask, and I'm stuck on a url generator.

I have an `@app.route` for my images:

```
@app.route('/images/<image>/')
def images(image):
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'images'), image)
```

Frozen-flask warns me that "*Nothing frozen for endpoints images. Did you forget an URL generator?*" so I try and generate a url generator like this

```
@freezer.register_generator
def images():
    path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'images')
    images = next(os.walk(path))[2]
    return images
```

which results in a `ValueError`: '404 NOT FOUND'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And your image tag looks like this `<img src="/images/somepic.jpg" />`?

Comment: @Drewness Yep. They do.

Comment: What this `<string:image>` means? I don't know the `string` filter.

Comment: @iurisilvio Yeah. That's pretty weird. It's not a real thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frozen-Flask generator expects an iterable with dictionaries:

```
@freezer.register_generator
def images():
    path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'images')
    images = next(os.walk(path))[2]
    for image in images:
        yield {"image": image}
```

The way you did it, you returned an iterable of strings, Frozen-Flask understand it as URLs instead of values.

If you want to return strings, you have to return the URL: `yield url_for('images', image=image)`

Also, your route should not have the trailing slash, because this way Frozen-Flask understand it is a folder where the default file there is an `index.html`. Remove the trailing slash: `@app.route('/images/<image>')`

Check the docs for more details: https://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#url-generators

Comment: That helped a bit. Though now I get `MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'index.html' (type text/html) does not match Content-Type: image/png` and my `images` folder contains folders with names like `someimage.png` containing an `index.html` with the actual image data in it.

Comment: @lejon just remove the trailing slash from your route. `@app.route('/images/<image>')`.