# Flask Frozen - 404 or Could not build url for endpoint error

Tags: flask

I'm trying out the Flask Frozen library to generate static pages, but am either getting 404 errors or "Could not build url for endpoint..." in my URL generator. I am using Flask 2.0.3 and Frozen-Flask 0.18

```
app = Flask(__name__)
freezer = Freezer(app)

# Then I initialise a SQL Alchemy DB connection - engine & metadata

# Then register my URL generator; I also tried giving the generator the same name as my function

@freezer.register_generator
def something():
    query, limit, offset = q_companies(engine, metadata, request.args)
    result = engine.execute(query)
    for row in result:
        # when I print this I can see the first value, but then the app crashes
        foo = row[0]    
                
        #this throws a 404 error
        # yield '/graphics/' + foo      
  
        # this throws a Could not build url for endpoint 'graphics' with values ['symbol']. Did you mean 'static' instead?
        # yield url_for('graphics', symbol=foo) 

        # this throws a Could not build url for endpoint 'graphics' with values ['symbol']. Did you mean 'static' instead?
        # yield {'symbol': foo}

        # this throws a 404 error
        # yield '/graphics/', {'symbol': foo}
```

My function, which is declared below the `if __name__ == 'main': freezer.freeze()` initialiser looks like this:

```
@app.route('/graphics/<symbol>')
def graphics(symbol):
    company, stats = get_overview_data(symbol) #SQLAlchemy query
    name = company['name']
    return render_template('combo.html', company=company, stats=stats, name=symbol)
```

I did look at this example but couldn't figure out what I may be doing wrong. [Problems with URL generator in Frozen-flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465427/problems-with-url-generator-in-frozen-flask)

As an aside, is Frozen-Flask still the defacto lib for this use case, or are there others out there?

PS: I should add that on first initialization Frozen did copy all my static assets to `build` as expected

Answer (score 0):

I needed to call freeze at the very bottom of my main file

```
if __name__ == 'main':
    freezer.freeze()
```